# Wordpress site suddenly stopped working

Tags: fatal-error

I'm working on a wordpress site, which has suddenly stopped working. Blank pages everywhere. It is a fresh site, and only I've made changes to it. The issue occured while I was building a custom template. This is the error message when I try to clear the cache with `wp cache flush`

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/Jillian/sites/wp2/site/web/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/Jillian/sites/wp2/site/web/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
```

Maybe someone with more wordpress experience than me can shed light on the problem?

Here are all the culprits:

Custom template: Test template

```
<!-- http://wp2.dev/44-2/ -->
<?php /* Template Name: Test Template */ 
function mypage_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/sass/style.css">'."\n"
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
get_header();

$page = get_post_meta(44);

// Dsiplay the page title (without >> in front)
$header    = $page['header'][0];
$subheader = $page['subheader'][0];

?>
<section class="span12" id="HomeHeader">
        <h1><?php echo $header; ?></h1>
        <div class="subtext"><?php echo $subheader; ?></div>
</section>
<section class="span12" id="HomeProjects">
    <?php
    // Display all projects
    $args = array('post_type' => 'project');
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) {

        $category    = get_field('category');
        $title       = the_title();
        $description = get_field('description');
        $link        = get_field('link');
        $link_title  = get_field('link_title');
        $image       = get_field('image');

    ?>
    <div class="project">
        <?php if( !empty($image) ): ?>
            <div class="project-image-container">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="subtext category"><?php echo $category; ?></div>
        <h2><?php $title; ?></h2>
        <div class="content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="read-more"><?php echo $link_title; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</section>
<section class="span12" id="HomeClients">
    <h1>Clients</h1>
    <?php
    //Display all clients
    $args  = array('post_type' => 'client');
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) {

        // $title = the_title();
        $icon = get_field('icon');
        $url  = get_field('link');
        $alt  = $icon['alt'] ? $icon['alt'] : get_field('title'); 

        ?>
    <div class="client">

        <?php if( !empty($icon) ): ?>
        <div class="client-img-container">
            <img src="<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php $alt; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">link</a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</section>
<section class="span12" id="HomeNews">
    <?php
    // Display news section
    $title           = $page['title'][0];
    $content         = $page['content'][0];
    $news_link       = $page['news_link'][0];
    $news_link_title = $page['news_link_title'][0];

    $args = array('post_type' => 'post'); // Query just regular posts
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    ?>
    <div class="posts">
        <div class="subtext">Latest</div>
        <?php
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            // setup_postdata($post);
            $date = date_format(date_create($post->post_date), 'jS F Y');
            ?>
            <div class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></div>
            <div class="content"><?php $post->post_content; ?></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
        <div class="content"><?php echo $content ?></div>
        <div class="btn news-link"><a href="<?php echo $news_link ?>"><?php echo $news_link_title ?></a></div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="span12" id="HomeCTA">
    <?php
    // Display CTA section
    $tagline        = $page['tagline'][0];
    $bold_text      = $page['bold_text'][0];
    $body           = $page['body'][0];
    $cta_link       = $page['cta_link'][0];
    $cta_link_title = $page['cta_link_title'][0];
    ?>
    <div class="cta">
        <div class="subtext"><?php echo $tagline ?></div>
        <h2 class="bold-text"><?php echo $bold_text ?></h2>
        <div class="content news-body"><?php echo $body ?></div>
        <div class="btn cta-link"><a href="<?php echo $cta_link ?>"><?php echo $cta_link_title ?></a></div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="span12" id="Hontact">
    <h3><?php echo $page['heading'][0]; ?></h3>
    <div class="subtext"><?php echo $page['subtext'][0]; ?></div>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $page['email'][0]; ?>"><?php echo $page['email'][0]; ?></a>
        <div><?php echo $page['phone'][0]; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $page['address'][0]; ?></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I also added a few variables and styles to `_elements.scss`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Lora:700i|Work+Sans:800');
$header-gray:  #5d6771;
$subtext-blue: #5ac3b6;

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background: $color__background-body; /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";

    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
    }
}

hr {
    background-color: $color__background-hr;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

@import "lists";

img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}

figure {
    margin: 1em 0; /* Extra wide images within figure tags don't overflow the content area. */
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: $header-gray;
    font: 800 51px/52px Work Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.subtext {
    color: $subtext-blue;
    font: italic bold 21px/25px 'Lora', serif;
}

@import "tables";
```

Thanks!

Jill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're getting tells you that your database settings aren't working to create a connection. Did you change your wp-config.php? Check that first. Then check that the database server is running.

```
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
```

Comment: Thanks! I restarted the server and the problem went away :)